# Implementing Ilayer interface in leaflet

Tags: javascript, function, interface, leaflet

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to implement the [Ilayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#ilayer) interface in Leaflet, but I'm having difficulties with the onRemove function. This layer consist of one core marker, which is always on the map, and some children markers which appear on click on the core marker.

**The problem**

When I use the removeLayer function I coded, it doesn't work as expected: if I have triggered the event first then it works fine. But if I haven't, the core marker isn't removed!

**The code**

```
L.CustomClusterGroup = L.FeatureGroup.extend({
    options: {

    },

    initialize: function(marker, options) {

        options = options || {};
        L.Util.setOptions(this, options);

        this.coreMarker = marker;

        L.FeatureGroup.prototype.initialize.call(this, []);

    },
    addTo: function(map) {

        this.coreMarker.addTo(map);
        var that = this;
        this.coreMarker.on( "click", function ()
        {
            L.FeatureGroup.prototype.addTo.call( that, map );
        } );
    },
    onRemove: function ( map ) {

        map.removeLayer(this.coreMarker);
        L.FeatureGroup.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);

    }
});
```

**My question**

I would like to understand why the code behaves like that, and the best way to fix it.

**EDIT**

I've a better understanding of the problem: the function onRemove don't get executed:

```
removeLayer: function (layer) {
    var id = L.stamp(layer);

    if (!this._layers[id]) { return; }

    if (this._loaded) {
        layer.onRemove(this);
        this.fire('layerremove', {layer: layer});
    }

    delete this._layers[id];
    if (this._zoomBoundLayers[id]) {
        delete this._zoomBoundLayers[id];
        this._updateZoomLevels();
    }

    // TODO looks ugly, refactor
    if (this.options.zoomAnimation && L.TileLayer && (layer instanceof L.TileLayer)) {
        this._tileLayersNum--;
        this._tileLayersToLoad--;
        layer.off('load', this._onTileLayerLoad, this);
    }

    return this;
},
```

So it's probable !this._layers[id] is false in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the code of leaflet and was able to fix the problem:

each map object has a propriety _layers which is an array indexing all the layers added to the map. So the addTo function should not add the features of the object on the map but pass the layer to the map with map.addLayer, which will be added to the _layers array. The map will then call the onAdd function.

If the addTo isn't coded that way, the layer wont be added to map._layers, and it will become impossible to remove it with the map functions.

```
    L.CustomClusterGroup = L.FeatureGroup.extend({
    options: {
        singleMarkerMode: true,


        //Options to pass to the L.Polygon constructor
        polygonOptions: {
            color: 'red',
            fillColor: 'red',
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.4
        }
    },

    initialize: function(marker, options) {

        options = options || {};
        L.Util.setOptions(this, options);


        this.coreMarker = marker;



        L.FeatureGroup.prototype.initialize.call(this, []);

    },
    addTo: function(map) {
        map.addLayer(this);
        return this;

    },
    onRemove: function(map) {

        map.removeLayer(this.coreMarker);
        L.FeatureGroup.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);
        this._map = null;

    },
    onAdd:function (map){
        this._map = map;
        map.addLayer( this.coreMarker );
        var that = this;
        this.coreMarker.on( "click", function ()
        {
            L.FeatureGroup.prototype.onAdd.call( that, map );

        } );
}
});
```

Comment: Just came across your question looking for ilayer info. Isn't the better way to solve the issue to add your coreMarker to your layer rather than the map? I think that's the main idea of the layer (it can contain other things). Once the layer is deleted, the contained elements will be removed..

Comment: This is exactly the undocumented behaviour I was looking for. You *must* call `map.addLayer(this);` in your `onAdd` callback in order for layer removal to work correctly.